# Google PageSpeed Insights API Quota

Tags: java, google-authentication, google-pagespeed, quota, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I was checking Google PageSpeed Insights API and I have question related to the quota but I cannot find answer for it on the web or on the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started) so appreciate if anyone can help or guide me in this point.
It is mentioned on the quota for this service that:

```
| requests per day | 25,000 | 
| requests per 100 seconds | Unlimited | 
| requests per 100 seconds per user | 100 |
```

In this case, If I am using the server key to authenticate google service API and get the required information, the number of requests from the server per 100 seconds will be max 100 request since all requests from the same server and with the same API Key or not?
What about the case of 100 requests per 100 seconds per user in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found the answer about the quota on google docs or the web but it is like the following:
1- In case of chrome extension or web application, each user "recognized by logged gmail account" can request 100 request per 100 seconds .
2- In case of the server, it will be unlimited per 100 seconds and 25000 per day.

I tested the server side and it does not have the restriction of 100 requests per 100 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think this information is more accurate.

> Google imposes a quota limit on PageSpeed Insights API usage. The
>   current limit (as of September, 2015) is 25,000 requests / day and 1
>   requests / second. The default pause is 1 second between sending
>   requests to Google to avoid exceeding quota.

Taken from following URL,

https://nodepit.com/node/com.mmiagency.knime.nodes.google.pagespeed.GooglePageSpeedNodeFactory

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a relationship between how many visitors you get to your site and their activity when it comes to Google Page Speed API rate limits. I think that if you exceed the rate limits because you had a lot of site visitors that Google will throttle or create other issues for your site, isn't that right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).